# Measuring time in Python

Tags: python

I have a function with measuring duration of other function and saving it in specific file:

```
def timeandsave(n, function, some_list, index=0):
    start=0
    gen(n, some_list)
    start = time.time()
    function(some_list)
    end = time.time() - start
    print 'Time: ' + str(end)
    plik = open('Sort' + str(n) + '_ind' + str(index) + '_result.txt', 'a')
    plik.write(str(end) + '\n')
    plik.close()
    return end
```

Now when I'm using for example:

```
timeandsave(10000, quick_sort_r, list, 1)
```

The answer is correct:

```
Time: 0.166000127792
```

But when I want to use it few times in a loop it's printing and saving a sum of results:

```
Input:
for i in range(0, 5):
    timeandsave(10000, quick_sort_r, list, 1)

Output:
Time: 0.173000097275
Time: 0.375999927521
Time: 0.577000141144
Time: 0.772000074387
Time: 0.962000131607
```

Any advice?

Comment: You might want to look at `timeit.Timer`.

Comment: Might because your `list` size is growing, you may check that first

Comment: what does `gen()` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all have a look at this link : http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Now for your code : 
In your main program you are passing list as an argument, this is assigned to some_list which is part of the parameter. Now if you modify some_list; even list will get modified.

Most probably when you use gen() you are modifying the size of some_list, in turn modifying 'list' itself. 

when you pass the list to some_copy, do a deep copy first or use a tuple instead of a list. (the latter is recommended).

#### option 1 :

```
def timeandsave(n, function, some_list, index=0):
  start=0
  my_list = copy.deepcopy(some_list)
  gen(n, my_list)
  #etc logic
  return end
```

#### option 2 :

```
def timeandsave(n, function, some_tuple, index=0):
  start=0
  #etc logic
```

Comment: I don't care about copy because elements are pseudo-random generated (this is what gen() do). But your advice whas correct! Size of list was growing up. 'some_list=[]' after 'start=0' is clearing the list every time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**timeandsave** returns the time it took to perform the function, so you can use this to find an average:

```
def runTrials(trials, n, func, list):
    total= 0.0
    for _ in range(trials):
        total+= timeandsave(n, func, list, 1)
    average= total/ trials
    file= open('AVERAGES.txt', 'a')
    file.write('Trials: '+str(trials)+ ', average: '+ str(average))
```

if you are using python 2, replace **range()** with **xrange()**, it will reduce memory usage. Also take a look at python's **timeit** module.